# Draw square and add values

Tags: tikz-datavisualization, draw

I want to add coordinates in the corners of a square grid.

Do you know how to place values in the vertices of square?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A square grid (3 × 3) with coordinates in the corners:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) grid (3, 3);
  \path
    (0, 0) node[below left] {$(0, 0)$}
    (3, 0) node[below right] {$(3, 0)$}
    (3, 3) node[above right] {$(3, 3)$}
    (0, 3) node[above left] {$(0, 3)$}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \path
    (0, 0) node[below left] {$(0, 0)$}
    (2, 0) node[below right] {$(2, 0)$}
    (2, 2) node[above right] {$(2, 2)$}
    (0, 2) node[above left] {$(0, 2)$}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Values can be placed with the same method.

Of course, there are many other tools and packages for more sophisticated plots like `pgfplots`. But these packages usually come with documentation and the question does not mention much details to write a meaningful example.

Comment: Sorry, but what should I do I wanted to put three square figures side by side ?

Comment: @johnjohn Square added.